# UPDATE Record in one table, with data from another table (seperate DB's) SSMS

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, ssms

I'm trying to create a script that I can use to resolve an issue with replication we experience in our Database structure.

Users will create a Master record in a Master database, and replication is used to push this down to all other DB's that form part of the subscription. From time to time, a change will be made in the master that needs to push down.

Unfortunately replication does not always work. Typically I resolve this through some simple SQL but recently I'm noticing entire records falling out of sync.

So I want to write a script that when this happens, I just insert a unique ID, and the subscribed record will update fully with the data from the Master.

To try explain, I was using something like this, but its returning a 0

```
update b 
set b.name = a.name,
<defined all columns>
from DatabaseA..crmast a
join DatabaseB..crmast b on a.crcode = b.crcode
where a.crcode = ''
```

DatabaseA is the Master (source)

DatabaseB is the subscriber (destination)

On Line three there, I've defined every column in the table (It's a big table...)

Where a.crcode ='' I enter the unique Crcode, which is the same in both tables. And then I want all the columns to be updated.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

So got this all sorted. Schoolboy error, was looking at the wrong Source table where the Crcode didn't exist.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14912939)

Comment: Well I guess it was more to indicate to other users that this can likely be ignored, as I realised the issue was of my own making